# Detecting if the user downloaded a file or not

Tags: sql-server, binary, logging, fileserver

I want to detect if the user has clicked on the download or the view hyperlinks. It's a page where people can upload files and if needed they can look at files too(files uploaded by anyone). I am uploading the files using asp.NET and storing it in the sql server database. These files are then displayed on the webpage using the database and can be seen by anyone who logs in. There are multiple files on the webpage and all have view or download links(files like zip files don't have view). I want to create a functionality that allows the user who uploaded the files to see who saw his/her file. Something like a table column for the file name and everyone watching the file getting added to the column in the database.
This is what I am using in the gridview:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/DownloadFile.aspx?Id={0}" HeaderText="Download" Text="Download" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to have your download/view/links/whatever go to a server-side component which records the click in a database before serving the file.

Comment: This is a much more reliable way to handle if the user returns to the same page multiple times. Otherwise Ahmad-San's jscript function would work for one-time visits.

Comment: I just wrote an sql query that updates the time if the user has already clicked on that button.

Answer (score 0):

in the HTML part use this for the button code:

```
<button type="button" onClick="check_download();"> Click Me </button>
```

and on the script part add this function

```
var downloaded = false;
function check_download() {
   if (downloaded == true ) {
      alert('You have already downloaded this file.');
      return false;
   } else {
      downloaded = true;
      document.location.href = 'http://Your.File.ToBe.Downloaded.URL';
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Users can click and download the files multiple times.

Comment: I updated the code, added a line to declare the (downloaded) variable and set it to false as default.